# Xml attributes on Android Google Maps doesn't work with AndroidStudio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm creating a simple Android app with Google Maps.
I've this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     map:cameraBearing="112.5"
    map:cameraTargetLat="45.438122"
    map:cameraTargetLng="12.318221"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="18"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="false"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="false"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/map"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

AndroidStudio tell me:

```
Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment
```

and it marks all lines with "map" prefix as errors also if the code seem ok to me.
Infact deploying my app I can see that all map tags are working on my Android device.

So I'm asking if it is only a small bug of AndroidStudio.

A little curiosity: using this layout instead AndroidStudio doesn't mark any error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraBearing="112.5"
map:cameraTargetLat="45.438122"
map:cameraTargetLng="12.318221"
map:cameraTilt="30"
map:cameraZoom="18"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiCompass="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="false"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
/>
```

Comment: do you have compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25' in your build.gradle ?

Comment: Sure. I repeat, the app works fine without problems. Seem to me only a problem of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace declaration in your `<FrameLayout>` element doesnt carry downwards into `<fragment>` namespace.  Your second example has the namespace declaration within the element that uses it (`<fragment>`) and Android Studio recognizes it immediately.